# How do I write an update function so that my edit form updates an existing text and replace it with something else?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, updating

Trying to write a simple update function that updates an ingredient and saves the new updated text. For some reason I can't figure it out. Upon Form submission I am getting nothing. Just the same ingredient that I was attempting to edit is returned.

Here is my code:

```js
editIngredient() {
  const ingredientId = this.parentElement.dataset.id
  var editForm = 
    `<form id="edit-form">
       <input type="text" id="edit-input">
       <input type="submit" value="Edit Ingredient">
     </form>`
  this.parentElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', editForm)
  console.log(this.parentElement)
  document.getElementById('edit-form')
  editForm.addEventListener("click", updateIngredient)
}
```

```js
renderIngredient(ingredientList){
  const li = document.createElement('li')
  li.dataset.id = this.recipe_id
  li.innerText = this.name
        
  const deleteBtn = document.createElement('button')
  deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", this.deleteIngredient)
  deleteBtn.innerText = "X"
  li.appendChild(deleteBtn)
  ingredientList.appendChild(li)

  const editBtn = document.createElement('button')
  editBtn.addEventListener("click", this.editIngredient)
  editBtn.innerText = "Edit"
  li.appendChild(editBtn)
  ingredientList.appendChild(li)
}
```

I know that I am new and uneducated but any help or template or even a helpful link would be so appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick sample I made which I hope will give you an idea:

**HTML**

```html
<ul>
  <li id="sugar">
    <label>Sugar</label>
    <button>Edit</button>
  </li>
  <li id="spice">
    <label>Spice</label>
    <button>Edit</button>
  </li>
  <li id="everything-nice">
    <label>Everything Nice</label>
    <button>Edit</button>
  </li>
</ul>

<form id="update-form">
  <input type="hidden" name="ingredientId"/>
  <input type="text" name="ingredientName"/>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

In the HTML form, I have three input fields:

1. A hidden field to keep track of the `li`'s ID which is selected to be edited. *You can leverage a JavaScript variable to keep track of this one too.*
2. An input text for the actual value.
3. And of course an input type submit to handle form submission.

**JavaScript**

```js
const updateForm = document.querySelector("#update-form");

// Here we attach a click event listener to all edit buttons
// with a process to set the update-form's input values.
document.querySelectorAll("li > button").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // Get the target's parent element which is in this case is the <li>
    let parentEl = e.target.parentElement;
    updateForm["ingredientName"].value = parentEl.querySelector("label").innerText;
    updateForm["ingredientId"].value = parentEl.id;
  });
});

// Form submit process 
updateForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  // To prevent the default submit action to occur.
  e.preventDefault(); 
  
  // Get the id of the li to update.
  let elementToUpdate = document.getElementById(this["ingredientId"].value);
  // Get the updated value of the ingredientName input box.
  let updatedLabel = this["ingredientName"].value;
  // Update the li label's inner HTML with the given input value.
  elementToUpdate.querySelector("label").innerHTML = updatedLabel;
});
```

Here's a CodePen link to see it in action:
https://codepen.io/nikkomina/pen/MWjzygo